# automatically testing a list of variables for a ks.test within code

Tags: r, statistics

I am running ks.tests on a long list of variables (about 15) in univariate and multivariate analysis. the goal of my analysis is to assess memory performance in different high and low risk categories for memory impairment. for example, "age" would be one variable, and in analysis with a single variable i would be comparing the memory scores of young (low risk) vs. old (high risk) participants. when looking at two variables i might compare age and education, so that would be young well educated (low risk) vs old low education (high risk) participants. and so on and so forth.

I have been going through and plugging in each variable to the same code. in single variate analysis that involved 15 of the same chunks of code with only the variable name changed. however when layering two and factors the number of code chunks started to grow exponentially. For example with two factor analysis i had to do age x all 15 other variables, sex x all 15 other variables, education x all 15 other variables and so on. i was wondering if there was a way that the chunk of code could automatically run each variable without me having to copy and paste it and change the variable name

```
newdataLOGOS$"risk factor"<- ifelse(newdataLOGOS$"risk factor"==0,1,
                                    ifelse(newdataLOGOS$"riskfactor"==1,2,0))

newdataLOGOSx"risk factor"lowrisk <- subset(newdataLOGOS, "risk factor"==1, 
                                            select = c("id","risk factor","memory score"))

newdataLOGOSx"risk factor"highrisk <- subset(newdataLOGOS, "risk factor"==2, 
                                             select = c("id","risk factor", "memory score"))

ks.test(newdataLOGOSx"risk factor"lowrisk$"memory score", 
        newdataLOGOSx"risk factor"highrisk$"memory score")
```